# Can we check if the new version is updated or not while using the service worker(Angular)

Tags: angular, service-worker

Can we check if the new version is updated or not while using the service worker(Angular)

#1 When I upload a new build we only get the first-time version update message but we need the second-time version update message

#2 Can we get every time which version is old and new

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Try to rephrase a bit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is SwUpdate.checkForUpdate(), but it has issues (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44402). The most reliable way is to implement method on server side that returns current version.